# Mapview shows White overlay on Interaction

Tags: swift, swiftui, mkmapview, navigationview, swiftui-navigationlink

I am using GMSMapView with SwiftUI, in map-view I have to display some markers with lat and long. Upon clicking any marker I have to Move to another view. I am doing this by putting MapView in **NavigationLink**. This thing is working fine By using code.

```
NavigationView {
    NavigationLink(destination: Text(""), isActive: $abc) {
        MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

And the issue is **NavigationLink**, after putting mapview in **NavigationLink** every-time when i interact with map, white overlay blinks. White overlay shows over complete map and  Images are attached with and without overlay.

[Screenshot without overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az0A5.jpg)

[Screenshot with overlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQq9T.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead

```
NavigationView {
    MapView().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .background(NavigationLink(destination: Text(""), 
        isActive: $abc) { EmptyView() })
}
```